# Ошибка в синтаксисе при создании UNIQUE INDEX в MS SQl

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь создать уникальный индекс который формируется на основании данных из нескольких столбцов БД. Но возникают синтаксические ошибки при описании таблицы. Вот код таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People_list] (
    [GUID]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [№]      NVARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    [ФИО]    NVARCHAR (60)    NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([№] ASC));
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [indx] ON [People_list] ([ФИО] ASC, [№] **ASC);**
**);**
```

В местах помеченных жирным шрифтом visual studio пишет следующую ошибку: incorrect syntax near ";" (в первом случае) и ")" (во втором).

Как исправить эти ошибки? Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последняя скобка и точка с запятой не нужны. Выражение `create table` завершено этой парой символов перед выражением `create index`.

Давайте слегка отформатируем приведённый код:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People_list] (
    [GUID]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [№]      NVARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    [ФИО]    NVARCHAR (60)    NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([№] ASC)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [indx] ON [People_list] ([ФИО] ASC, [№] ASC);
```

Вот так правильно.

Comment: Спасибо, еще пришлось добавить "GO" перед вторым CREATE.